# How to set audio delay when muxing with FFmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, delay

I have the following command for muxing audio and video with FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "D:\Project\Output.webm" -i "D:\Project\Vorbis.ogg" -c copy -aspect 16:9 "D:\Project\Final.webm"
```

Audio is early by about 1500 ms.

How do I sync audio with video?

Comment: No time for a full answer, but to get you started research the `itsoffset` and `map` options for FFMpeg.